# How can I share an Excel sheet with embedded SQL queries with another user without asking them for log-in credentials?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server

I created an Excel (Microsoft 365) sheet for a (non-tech-savvy) coworker that pulls data from a SQL database. However, he is not able to refresh the queries (by hitting 'Refresh All') on his machine because he does not have access to the database. When he tries to refresh, it asks him for log-in credentials that he does not have.

Is there any way for me to send him the sheet and have it stay logged in with my credentials? It would be best if he never had to enter any log-in information and could just hit refresh to update the queries.

Comment: Yes, if your company is properly setup. Search for `excel services authentication settings` to find out if this is an option.

Comment: You don't want him using your credentials as they probably have write/delete permissions, and if he messes up it will show up as you doing it on an audit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

Main()

Sub Main()  
    
   Dim cn,rs        
' bring on the databse access
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=<server_name>;Database=database_name;User=username; Password=password;"
    'connectionString = "Driver={MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver};Server=server_name;Database=database_name; User=username; Password=password;"
    cn.Open connectionString
    rs.ActiveConnection = connectionString 
        rs.Open "select concat(""
```

If you added a macro you could embed a username and password with only read access.  I don't know how your using it,but you might have to add more code into the macro.  You might have to move the embedded SQL queries into one or more macros.